# Strange errors when run ruby script in "Daemon.run" and no errors in case "bundle exec ruby"

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra, daemon, koala

I write sinatra based application with Daemons gem, app oAuth oh facebook and change cover of some page. So when i call daemon directly from "bundle exec ruby daemon.rb" no error in output, but when i run this daemon trought Daemons.run with log, i see many errors:

like this:

```
E, [2013-03-29T19:04:15.762886 #40814] ERROR -- : method `_create_callbacks' not defined in Class (NameError)
E, [2013-03-29T19:04:15.767114 #40814] ERROR -- : method `_active_authorizer' not defined in Class (NameError)
E, [2013-03-29T19:04:15.767434 #40814] ERROR -- : method `_protected_attributes' not defined in Class (NameError)
E, [2013-03-29T19:04:15.774713 #40814] ERROR -- : uninitialized constant MIME (NameError)
E, [2013-03-29T19:04:15.775264 #40814] ERROR -- : uninitialized constant Koala::HTTPService::MIME (NameError)
E, [2013-03-29T19:04:15.775527 #40814] ERROR -- : uninitialized constant Koala::MIME (NameError)
E, [2013-03-29T19:04:15.776317 #40814] ERROR -- : uninitialized constant Koala::HTTPService::UploadableIO::MIME (NameError)
```

and

```
E, [2013-03-29T19:04:15.779144 #40814] ERROR -- : read would block (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
```

I use gem Koala, Sinatra/activerecord

I don't understand why this happend?

**PS:**

I have daemon controll script run_daemon.rb

```
 require 'daemons'
 ....
 file = file passed with argument
 Daemons.run(file, options)
```

inside each file of daemon I load application config, on top of this config i place "require 'bundler/setup'"

when I run from daemon controll, in log I have errors

```
 bundle exec ruby run_daemon.rb daemon_name start
```

but when I run directly without demonyze

```
 bundle exec ruby path_do_daemon/daemon_name.rb
```

no errors

Comment: Hi Alex. Have you got `Bundler.setup` or `Bundler.require` somewhere near the start of your initialization code?

Comment: Hello, Iain. in my primary init script require 'bundler/setup', it same as Bundler.setup or not?

Comment: That should be enough. What's the exact command you use when the error occurs?

Comment: I wrote addon explanation in question